# Craft on WSL permissions error

Tags: craft3, error-message, permissions, windows

*For anyone installing install Craft on WSL (Windows Services for Linux)...*

WSL has enough traction with developers that I decided to take the dive, but I'm having trouble getting permissions straight with my Craft install.

Apparently, PHP doesn't have permission to chmod inside the project folders, which generates this error on login to Craft.

> Failed to change permissions for directory
>   "/mnt/c/Users/jimme/sites/mywebsite/craft/web/cpresources/6d799f01":
>   chmod(): Operation not permitted
>
> Caused by: yii\base\ErrorException
>   chmod(): Operation not permitted
>   in /mnt/c/Users/jimme/sites/jm/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseFileHelper.php >at line 646

UPDATE:

I've modified my /etc/wsl.conf file to add support for linux metadata, which allows permissions to be set granularly for files in the windows filesystem. I've also changed changed the ownership to myuser:www-data and added group write perms. After making this change it fixed the above error but now I'm getting this on login...

> HTTP 400 – Bad Request – yii\web\BadRequestHttpException Unable to
>   verify your data submission.
>
> in /mnt/c/Users/jimme/sites/jm/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Controller.php

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All fixed. The solution was to add these mount options to /etc/wsl.conf to allow metadata support. Also had to rename (or delete) /storage/cpresources and clear cache.

> [automount]
>   enabled=true
>   options=metadata,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022

From Microsoft on permissions in WSL:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/

Answer (score 2):

This worked well for me!

Be sure to change directory out of the drive you want to unmount first!

Just to keep it all together here is what you need to do -

> sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf

Paste this into the open file -

```
[automount]
enabled=true
options=metadata,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022
```

Then paste and enter these one at a time into Terminal -

> sudo rm /your_craft_path_to/cpresources
>
> cd /var/www
>
> sudo umount /mnt/c
>
> sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata
>
> sudo service apache2 restart

Head to your Craft URL and et voila!

Comment: Thank you, this works